# Hibernate CriteriaBuilder Case Statements: How to get avg() salary Based on Condition Using CriteriaBuilder with Case statement.?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am new to Hibernate and I want to run below MySQL query using Hibernate criteriaBuilder.

```
mysql> select avg(case when id=1 then 30 when id=2 then 30 else 0 end) as avg_age from student;
```

What I tried :

```
    CriteriaBuilder builder = HibernateUtil.getCriteriaBuilder();
        EntityManager em = HibernateUtil.getEntityManager();
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> query = builder.createQuery(Object[].class);
Root<Student> teacher = query.from(Student.class);
    query.multiselect(builder.avg(
        teacher.get("salary")),
         builder.selectCase()
        .when(builder.equal(teacher.get("id"), 1), 30)
        .when(builder.equal(teacher.get("id"), 2), 30)
        .otherwise(0));

    List<Object[]> results = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    for(Object[] object: results){
        System.out.println("Avg Salary = " + object[0] );
    }

    }
```

It is executing separately avg() function and case statement. I have Student table having id,age,salary,name,adds columns, I want avg() salary of student but those having id (1 and 2) set salary 30 and for others 0.

Comment: do u want to get avg() age or salary?

Comment: sorry avg() salary .please see edit

Comment: Please help me, Still i did not get it.

Comment: OK , will try? If anyone knows please help.

Comment: @Raj Instead of calculating average like this, you can get the count of `id=1,2` and then multiply it with 30 and divide this value by `count(*)`